# inconsistent `apt-get update` behaviour on official Ubuntu AWS AMI

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, apt, amazon-ami, packer

I get various and inconsistent errors with `apt` on the official Ubuntu images (`ami-83e769fb`). I'm using Packer to build my AMI and it fails about 40% of the time. Rerunning the script succeeds.

My script runs:

```
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get update
```

before install any packages.

Some times I get this error:

```
amazon-ebs: W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_InRelease into data and signature failed
amazon-ebs: E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease' is not signed.
```

Some times `apt-get update` hits `http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` ... other times it doesn't.

Other times packages are missing (like `apache2` or `python3`).

I don't understand why this behaviour is inconsistent.

How can I get `apt-get update` on the official Ubuntu AMI to work consistently?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `cloud-init` you can wait for it to complete.

```
while [ ! -f /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished ]; do
   echo 'Waiting for cloud-init...'
   sleep 1
done
```

e.g. packer json:

```
{
  "type": "shell",
  "inline": [
    "while [ ! -f /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished ]; do echo 'Waiting for cloud-init...'; sleep 1; done"
  ]
}
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/2639
- https://www.packer.io/docs/other/debugging.html

Comment: You could use `cloud-init status --wait` to wait for cloud-init, instead of that loop.

Answer (score 2):

packer.json before provision:

```
"provisioners": [
    {
       "type": "shell",
       "inline": ["/usr/bin/cloud-init status --wait"]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue myself and I believe it happens because cloud-init is still in the process of configuring the EC2 instance when `apt-get` runs. I solved it by inserting a 30 second delay in my script that runs immediately after the instance boots. I think a better way would be to ask cloud-init to run any scripts through `User Data` or even letting it handle package installation and updates for you [1]. For my use case, where I don't want to acknowledge cloud-init, adding the delay was an acceptable solution.

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html